# upload file to s3 using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

I have coded a function which upload file to s3 which using `aws-sdk`, but I've got a problem.

When I replace `Body` by `Body: "test"` then the function will execute successfully and I can see the content `test` in `s3`.

But I want to upload a document such as *pdf* file, it can't run and throws an error as:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
>   The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL.
>   Received type object at Object.open (fs.js:406:3) at ReadStream.open
>   (internal/fs/streams.js:110:12) at new ReadStream
>   (internal/fs/streams.js:99:10) at Object.createReadStream
>   (fs.js:1725:10)

This is my code:

```
import { createWriteStream, createReadStream } from "fs";
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const fs = require('fs');


const uploadS3 = async ({file}) => {
  const { stream, filename} = file;
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '*******',
    secretAccessKey: '********',
    region: 'us-east-1' 
  });

  let params = {
    Bucket: "test-files-staging",
    Key: 'documents/' + filename,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(file),
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };
  await new AWS.S3().putObject(params).promise().then(() => {
    console.log('Success!!!')
  }).catch((err) => { console.log(`Error: ${err}`) })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Well the error is pretty clear: the `path` argument needs to be string, buffer or URL, but you pass in an object which is the readStream created by fs.createReadStream.

Instead, use the `fs.readFileSync` function to read your file into a buffer (if you use the async `fs.readFile` you'll get a promise- which is again neither a string, buffer or URL and will fail again):

```
let params = {
    Bucket: "test-files-staging",
    Key: 'documents/' + filename,
    Body: fs.readFileSync(filename), // assuming filename is the full path to your object
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };
```

more info on `fs` functions can be found in documentation- [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

Comment: i changed as your answer, but i got an error as:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'documet_1.pdf'`

Comment: watch my comment, the `filename` has to be a **full** path to the file you're trying to load

Comment: @KhanhPham did it help you? if so please accpet the answer, or elaborate if you ran into another problem :)